# iOS/Android Phonegap - portrait for smartphones, landscape on tablets

Tags: android, ios, cordova, orientation, media-queries

I'm creating a multidevice multiplatform app with Phonegap.

Basically, I have two scenarios:

- Smartphones should be locked to portrait mode.
- Tablets should be locked to landscape mode.

I should be able to customize the layout and placement with media queries, depending if the device is a tablet or smartphone (landscape or portrait, respectively).
I've experimented with locking to portrait regardless of device, and then using CSS media queries and rotate transformations, but I run with two problems:

- I haven't been able to find a media query that targets tablets and excludes smartphones and viceversa, the universe of resolutions seems to be too sparse.
- Working with `body{transform:rotate(90deg)}` looks like a nightmare to nail everything down.

I also looked into: https://github.com/champierre/pg-plugin-screen-orientation but it seems to be working only for Android and I need to support both iOS and Android.

Does anyone have any experience with this particular scenario? Any suggestions on handling this orientation problem?

Comment: I'm having the same requirement (iOS & Android, portrait for smartphone, landscape for tablets). What did you ended up doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `navigator.userAgent` to get the device type. For Example something like this:

```
var deviceType = (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i))  == "iPad" ? "iPad" : (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i))  == "iPhone" ? "iPhone" : (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)) == "Android" ? "Android" : (navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i)) == "BlackBerry" ? "BlackBerry" : "null";

alert(navigator.userAgent);
```

Or you can use the guide in [this page...](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_device_device.md.html)

After that you can use the following code to set the orientation:

```
$(window).bind('orientationchange', function(event){

    if (/*is tablet*/) {
     navigator.screenOrientation.set('landscape');
    } 
    else if (/* is smart phone */) {
     navigator.screenOrientation.set('portrait');
    }

   });
```

I hope that above codes be helpful for you ;)

Comment: Thanks! Looks like a great starting point. However the simple user-agent detection is complicated to distinguish between any tablets and phones. I found this library: http://blog.mobileesp.com/ which seems to be working, I'll so some tests and update on the results!

Comment: So I've been able to detect correctly between phones and tablets (will post code later), but I believe the solution of setting the screenOrientation only works on Android? The second chunk of code uses the Android-only plugin I had explored? https://github.com/champierre/pg-plugin-screen-orientation